# Nominatim - from Point to Polygon (town, city boundary)

Tags: reverse-geocoding, nominatim

I'm struggling with Nominatim's **Search** and **Reverse**.

What I want, is **to reverse geocode a Point and get a (Multi)Polygon. An administrative boundary (town, city scale preferred).**

- reverse geocoding: sometimes identifies neighbouring town/city
  instead.
- search: input coordinates. Still identifies neighbouring
  town/city instead.

Example:
[Nominatim Reverse lookup for Point](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?&lat=50.930629808303365&lon=8.41129519164891&zoom=12&addressdetails=1&polygon_geojson=1&format=json)

Result mentions **Bad Berleburg**. If you look that up, the point is not in the polygon for Bad Berleburg. Somehow I should derive a boundary for **Bad Laasphe** I guess (so from the point I actually need to derive this boundary, for which I don't know the name in advance without reverse geocoding).

I'm looking to accomplish this with a free API, preferably Nominatim. This is my fallback method. I'm using a database with GADM shapes for the 2 most common countries, but I don't want to import all the cities in the world in that database by default.

Update: I've been pointed to the Overpass API for this, looking into it now. Looks promising.

Comment: Did you ever get to accomplish this? I am interested in doing something similar

Comment: It's been too long, I think I managed to pull it off with the Overpass API at that time.